# What is the story of Vishnu incarnating as a mango tree in the Dandaka forest?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, avatars, sri-vaishnava

The Sri Vaishnava sect has two sub-sects, Thenkalai and Vadakalai. Vadakalais follow the teachings of Vedanta Desikan, whereas Thenkalais follow the teachings of Pillai Lokacharya.  My question is about Pillai Lokacharya.  In [this excerpt](https://archive.org/stream/tattvatrayaoraph00pilluoft#page/136/mode/2up) from his Tattva Traya, Pillai Lokacharya discusses the different forms of Vishnu described in the Pancharatra worldview - Para, Vyuha, Vibhava, Antaryami, and Archa.  In particular, Vibhava refers to Vishnu's avataras or incarnations:

> Of His own sovereign will alone, the Lord becomes a secondary incarnation, just as, of His sovereign will alone, He, in his primary incarnations, chooses to manifest Himself by His own all-transcendant form look like the form of a man, beast, or **plant**.

I'm interested in the part in bold.  Vishnu's various incarnations as humans and animals are well-known, but I've never heard of him incarnating as a plant.  Here is what the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Prathivadi Bhayankaram Annangaracharya says in his [commentary](http://acharya.org/bk/pb/GSI/TTSM-GSI.pdf) on the Tattva Traya:

> Vibhava or the incarnate forms of the Lord are infinite in number, with the difference that some of them are primary while the others are only secondary.  The primary avatars like Rama, Krishna, Matsya, Kurma, etc., **the dwarf mango tree in Dandakaranya**, etc., arose through the Lord's will.

My question is, what is the story of Vishnu's incarnation as a dwarf mango tree in the Dandaka forest?  The Dandaka forest is where Rama, Lakshmana, and Sita were living when Sita was kidnapped by Ravana.

So does this tree play a role in the Ramayana? Page 220 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=evmiLInyxBMC&pg=PA220&lpg=PA220&dq=%22mango+tree%22+dandaka&source=bl&ots=a_oTpyFfVV&sig=sIzF3hsB58TJ14izy6daZNLXXT8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj32dq8xtfaAhUMU98KHfOdAycQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ) says that that Vishnu's mango tree incarnation is mentioned in the Vishvaksena Samhita, one of the Pancharatra Agamas.  But it's never beeen translated into English.

Comment: Visvaksena Samhita is available in Telugu as ebook
https://www.amazon.in/Viswaksena-Samhita-Jeeyar-Educational-Trust-ebook/dp/B06XRQJY8W

Comment: Out of his own will.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Haha yeah, but I want the story.  I'm thinking it might even be something as simple as "Vishnu took the form of a mango tree to provide shade to Sita."

Comment: Wow would be an interesting story!

Comment: I also read that it is in Vishvaksena Samhita, but couldn't find it online. Here's what I could find, "This sacred tree in Hinduism has been mentioned in Ramayana, Mahabharata and the Puranas. The fruit is a symbol of love, purity and fertility. The mango tree leaves are used in several rituals and pujas. According to the ancient believers, mango leaves symbolise life."—https://www.boldsky.com/yoga-spirituality/faith-mysticism/2013/sacred-hindu-trees-and-plants-033284.html

Comment: Vishnu sustains life; he holds the conch which can produce the Om. The sound of Om vibrates life into being. Vishnu is pure; he holds the lotus blossom & discus. The lotus has risen through the muck, using it to grow. On the surface sits the blossom, pure and untouched by the muck. The discus is used to destroy unholy or impure beings. It represents destruction of ego mind which leads one to a pure thoughts. So, with its fruit of purity and its leaves of life, the mango tree symbolically represents Vishnu. So, perhaps this is why he incarnated as one. Why that one specifically I can't find.